# JavaCC - How to store tokens for later parse?

Tags: token, javacc, any

I'm trying to parse my input partially, so that I can store certain chunks for a later parse.

```
void start():{}
{
    stmt()*
}

void stmt():{}
{
    "parse:" expr_later() ";"
}

void expr_later():{}
{
    (
    expr();
    // store tokens from expr() in a list for later processing....
    )*
}

void expr():{}
{
    "{" expr() "}"
|    <ANY:~[]>
}
```

In this case, the "ANY" token will only be valid if previous tokens didn't match anything else, but assuming I have many more token definitions, the grammar above won't do.

I know that `~[]` matches any character and *not* any token.

Further, let's say I would use token states instead (stuff they do with javadoc, pragmas etc.), I would still have a problem capturing the chunks, since I don't have any token to set my special token state. Also, setting the token state via the parser seems to be a bad practice according to JavaCC's FAQ, since the TokenManager might already have some tokens in its queue.

So I'm wondering if there's any ANY-equivilent regarding tokens. Or does someone at least have an idea how to approach my problem in a different way?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is *bad* practice to change lexical state from the parser. It does require careful consideration of how much lookahead the parser has already done.

Comment: Well, as you mentioned, I would still have to make sure that the queue is clear before I change states. And they actually have a solution how to handle such cases in their FAQ, but it still doesn't feel right, simply because I have to do extra work and modifications in order for the parser to proceed properly. Too hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course one way to do it is to make a big production that lists every kind of token except "{" and "}".

```
Token any() :{Token t;}{ (t=<NUMBER> | t=<IDENTIFIER> | t="(" | ... | ) {return t;} }
```

But that's not at all elegant.

Instead, you can write a `JAVACODE` production that consumes tokens until the final close-brace is found.  See https://javacc.java.net/doc/javaccgrm.html#JAVACODE for a similar example.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. Not the JAVACODE production, but the lazy way, implementation of the any() rule. Later on I'll probably move to the JAVACODE stuff. Looks pretty good to me, except that there would be a problem using it among choice points, but it seems that it could be resolved with LOOKAHEAD specifications. Thanks for the info!